# Ultimate GPS Logger Shield : Soft Serial Sketch Error

Tags: tinygps

Im using a OSEPP Uno R3 Plus to connect with a Ultimate GPS Logger Shield. I am currently working through the Adafruit Ultimate GPS Logger Shield pdf. When connecting in Soft Serial Mode and loading a parsing sketch. In the com window my values are showing but unreadable. I have included an image. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You should describe your problem with further details if you expect some help. Currently I get no idea of what you have done so far to get there (eg source code). It seems likely you have an issue with `Serial`configuration, but without any code, it is hard to tell. Also you did not mention how the serial console is setup (speed in particular).

Answer (score 1):

jfpoilpret > My apologies for not including enough information and details. But your comments did lead to me resolving my issue. I did not change my baud rate to match the baud rate of the source code and the script is working now. Appreciated.